# Solubility curve for uranium hexafluoride (in any solvent)

Tags: solubility, reference-request

I am doing a project and need a solubility curve or at least solubility data for uranium hexafluoride in any substance. It is impossible for water because $\ce{UF6}$ reacts violently with $\ce{H2O}$.

Is there any resource I could use for free to find this information?

Comment: You can use mhchem (`$\ce{H2O}$`) to write chemical formulas, it will save you a few keystrokes and it looks neat.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I usually go on math SE or physics SE so I am not used to chem SE format.

Comment: No worries, this is a short help article for formatting on Chem.SE: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here

Comment: "normal MathJax" still works too, but the extra `\ce` turns on the chemistry-specific stuff

Comment: I don't have the time to look through it, but did you already try [DOI:  10.2172/4025868](https://www.osti.gov/scitech/biblio/4025868/). Have you tried other databases yet? Please add them to avoid doubling the effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far I have found that it is soluble in:

1. [Bromine Pentafluoride](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01648a017?journalCode=jacsat)
2. [Chlorotrifluoroethylene Liquid Polymer, Dichlorotetrafluoroethane, Perfluorotributylamine, Perfluoroisopropyl ether, 1,2-Dichlorohexafluoropropane, hydrogen fluoride and more.](https://www.osti.gov/scitech/biblio/4025868/)
3. [chloroform,  carbon  tetrachloride  and  fluorocarbon  solvents;

   liquid chlorine and bromine; dissolves in nitrobenzene to form a dark red solu-
   tion that fumes in air](ftp://pvictor.homeftp.net/public/Sci_Library/Chem%20Library/Handbooks/Patnaik%20P.%20Handbook%20of%20inorganic%20chemicals%20(MGH,%202003)(T)(1125s).pdf)

I think the resource given by Martin (2) is the best. Resource 1 gives a solubility curve, but resource 3 doesn't. However, I think there may be data floating around on compounds mentioned by 3.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia states](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium_hexafluoride) that reacts [violently with water*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022113900807150) but is soluble in chloroform($\ce{CCl4}$), liquid chlorine/bromine and
dissolves in nitrobenzene.

[This paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/je00036a028) discuss solubility of uranium hexafluoride in some low temperature solvents.

> Solubility of $\ce{UF6}$ has been studied in liquefied gases like phosgene,
>   nitrous dioxide and sulfur dioxide below 273K. The solubilities were
>   compared using real and ideal gas theory and found out that phosgene
>   provide better solubility than sulfur dioxide. Solubility of $\ce{UF6}$ has
>   also been studied on halocarbons and fluorinated halocarbons** all below
>   273K.

** **Perfluoroether** is widely used as a solvent for $\ce{UF6}$. There are many papers which  discuss this topic and can be found on Google. The following is an abstract of [one of the papers.](https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:18050357)

> The polyperfluoroethers are compatible with uranium hexafluoride
>   ($\ce{UF6}$) and are suitable for use in diffusion pumps and in
>   mechanical vacuum pumps which rely on oil as both the lubricant and
>   the seal. The $\ce{UF6}$ is soluble in all fluids with which it is
>   compatible. Because a number of vacuum pumps in the BOP facilities of
>   the GCEP plant employ these perfluoroether oils as the working fluid
>   and have oil chambers which are large, questions have been raised as
>   to the relationships governing the solubility of $\ce{UF6}$ in these
>   materials and the maximum quantities of $\ce{UF6}$ which could be
>   dissolved in these oils under credible accident conditions. This
>   report summarizes these solubility relations and the interaction of
>   the  $\ce{UF6}$ solubility and the pumping capability of this type of
>   vacuum pump. **It will be shown that, whereas the solubility of
>   $\ce{UF6}$ in Fomblin Y25 fluoroether fluid under a
>   $\ce{UF6}$ pressure of 760 torr and at the pump operating temperature
>   of 1600F is about 500 g of $\ce{UF6}$ per liter of oil, the system
>   controls are such as to isolate the system from the pumps before the
>   quantity of $\ce{UF6}$ dissolved in the perfluoroether exceeds about
>   10 g of $\ce{UF6}$ per liter of oil.**

---

*
[image]